# Таймер для циклической видеозаписи

Tags: java, android, таймер

Суть простая - сделать бесконечный цикл коротких видеозаписей как на видеорегистраторах. Даже стыдно спросить - как осуществить такой цикл? Вроде всё просто, вроде и циклы уже делал, а вот для этого дела ну никак не получатся. Конечно же, категорично выполнение по-человечески - в отдельном потоке, например Handler. Буду рад любой подсказке кроме "гугл в помощь" и `SystemClock.sleep();` =)

Алгоритм:

```
VideoOn(); // сноска на метод начала записи

*Таймер ожидания конца видео.

VideoOff(); // сноска на метод окончания видеозаписи 

*Повторить цикл заново.
```

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать таймер для решения своей проблемы.

```
        //import java.util.Timer;
        //import java.util.TimerTask;
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        int seconds = 5;
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("1234");
            }
        }, 0, seconds * 1000); // 1 секунда 1000 миллисекунд.
```

Comment: место: System.out.println("1234");  -->> VideoOff(); VideoOn();